# Trackbars to isolate a color in an image are not working as expected

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

This code is suppose to isolate a particular color in an image.

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

const int max_value_H = 360 / 2;
const int max_value = 255;
const String window_detection_name = "Object Detection";
int low_H = 0, low_S = 0, low_V = 0;
int high_H = max_value_H, high_S = max_value, high_V = max_value;
static void on_low_H_thresh_trackbar(int, void*)
{
    low_H = min(high_H - 1, low_H);
    setTrackbarPos("Low H", window_detection_name, low_H);
}
static void on_high_H_thresh_trackbar(int, void*)
{
    high_H = max(high_H, low_H + 1);
    setTrackbarPos("High H", window_detection_name, high_H);
}
static void on_low_S_thresh_trackbar(int, void*)
{
    low_S = min(high_S - 1, low_S);
    setTrackbarPos("Low S", window_detection_name, low_S);
}
static void on_high_S_thresh_trackbar(int, void*)
{
    high_S = max(high_S, low_S + 1);
    setTrackbarPos("High S", window_detection_name, high_S);
}
static void on_low_V_thresh_trackbar(int, void*)
{
    low_V = min(high_V - 1, low_V);
    setTrackbarPos("Low V", window_detection_name, low_V);
}
static void on_high_V_thresh_trackbar(int, void*)
{
    high_V = max(high_V, low_V + 1);
    setTrackbarPos("High V", window_detection_name, high_V);
}
int main()
{
    Mat result, frame, frame_HSV;
    Mat frame_threshold;
    frame = imread("D:/mmm.bmp");
    namedWindow(window_detection_name);
    createTrackbar("Low H", window_detection_name, &low_H, max_value_H, on_low_H_thresh_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("High H", window_detection_name, &high_H, max_value_H, on_high_H_thresh_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("Low S", window_detection_name, &low_S, max_value, on_low_S_thresh_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("High S", window_detection_name, &high_S, max_value, on_high_S_thresh_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("Low V", window_detection_name, &low_V, max_value, on_low_V_thresh_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("High V", window_detection_name, &high_V, max_value, on_high_V_thresh_trackbar);
    while (true) {
        cvtColor(frame, frame_HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(frame_HSV, Scalar(low_H, low_S, low_V), Scalar(high_H, high_S, high_V), frame_threshold);
        bitwise_and(frame, frame, result, frame_threshold);
        imshow(window_detection_name, result);
        waitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However it does not change the image, no matter how much I move the trackbars.
If I change the imshow(window_detection_name, result); to imshow(window_detection_name, frame_threshold); it works more or less. But I want the actual image, not the black and white mask.

That means this bitwise operator is not working properly.

bitwise_and(frame, frame, result, frame_threshold);

If I remove all the trackbars and update the parameters manually in inrange function, everything works fine. Thus the problem is formed when I use trackbars with bitwise_and.

I picked most of the code from official tutorial.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html

I have tried using getTrackbarPos, it has the exact same issue.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

const int max_value_H = 360 / 2;
const int max_value = 255;
const String window_detection_name = "Object Detection";
int low_H = 0, low_S = 0, low_V = 0;
int high_H = max_value_H, high_S = max_value, high_V = max_value;
void donothing(int, void*){}
int main()
{
    Mat result, frame, frame_HSV;
    Mat frame_threshold;
    frame = imread("D:/mmm.bmp");
    namedWindow(window_detection_name);
    createTrackbar("Low H", window_detection_name, &low_H, max_value_H, donothing);
    createTrackbar("High H", window_detection_name, &high_H, max_value_H, donothing);
    createTrackbar("Low S", window_detection_name, &low_S, max_value, donothing);
    createTrackbar("High S", window_detection_name, &high_S, max_value, donothing);
    createTrackbar("Low V", window_detection_name, &low_V, max_value, donothing);
    createTrackbar("High V", window_detection_name, &high_V, max_value, donothing);
    while (true) {
        cvtColor(frame, frame_HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        low_H =  getTrackbarPos("Low H", window_detection_name);
        low_S = getTrackbarPos("Low S", window_detection_name);
        low_V = getTrackbarPos("Low V", window_detection_name);
        high_H = getTrackbarPos("High H", window_detection_name);
        high_S = getTrackbarPos("High S", window_detection_name);
        high_V = getTrackbarPos("High V", window_detection_name);
        inRange(frame_HSV, Scalar(low_H, low_S, low_V), Scalar(high_H, high_S, high_V), frame_threshold);
        bitwise_and(frame, frame,  result, frame_threshold);
        imshow(window_detection_name, result);
        waitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When moving the trackbars, does imshow(..., frame_threshold) update as expected?

Comment: mmm... maybe `bitwise_and(frame, frame_threshold, result)`?

Comment: @Guang frame_threshold does update. Yes.

Comment: @beaker this gives an error, it requires 4 arguments. 2 input images, result and mask.  https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14

Comment: @user541396 "mask - **optional** operation mask, 8-bit single channel array, that specifies elements of the output array to be changed"

Comment: @beaker Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in cv::binary_op,

Comment: Ah, I would think that's because `frame` is 3-channel and `frame_threshold` is 1?

Comment: @beaker  That is what I assume.  Yes.